# Hooks Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize-js

Para fins de entendimento: Node.js com banco postgres rodando com Sequelize v4;

Alguns campos de meu banco de dados precisam ser persistidos em banco com criptografia, por exigência de negócio.

Utilizando os hooks beforeCreate, e beforeBulkUpdate consigo encriptar no banco, e isso está funcionando.
Também utilizo o hook afterFind para descriptografar os dados ao recuperá-los, e isso também está OK.

Meu problema é que, quando uso o afterBulkUpdate para descriptografar os dados que foram inseridos, os mesmos não aparecem pra o usuário descriptografado. Segue um pequeno exemplo:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      full_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notNull: {
            msg: VALIDATIONS_MESSAGES.FULL_NAME,
          },
          notEmpty: {
            args: true,
            msg: VALIDATIONS_MESSAGES.FULL_NAME,
          },
        },
      });

  User.afterBulkUpdate(async (entity, options) => {
    entity.attributes = decryptPersonalData(entity.attributes);
    return entity;
  });
```

Ao retornar, os dados aparecem ainda criptografados na API. Alguma idéia do que posso usar?

Comment: Se esses dados ainda aparecem criptografados, provavelmente esse Hook não foi chamado. Como é feita essa chamada para executar esse Hook? Provavelmente, métodos que envolvem `Bulk` precisam de alguma parâmetro como `individualHooks: true` para disparar esse Hook.

Comment: O Hook foi chamado, eu consigo fazer console.log na chamada do hook. A questão é que a alteração realizada no objeto dentro do hook não é enviada no retorno no serviço.
Os hooks individuais estão ok.